# Generating function for non-isomorphic regular graphs.

Tags: graph-theory, generating-functions

Determine a generating function for the number of non-isomorphic (n−2)-regular graphs of order n, for n ≥ 2.

I've been staring at this for hours and can't find a place to start, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please edit the question. This will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers

Comment: You can start by drawing all the ones you can for relatively small values of $n$ so that you could form the start of a sequence to check with OEIS.

Comment: I'd enumerate the complements of the given graphs.

Answer (score 1):

We enumerate the complements, namely non-isomorphic 2-regular graphs.
These are sets of cycles and we find

$$\prod_{k\ge 3} \frac{1}{1-z^k}
= (1-z)(1-z^2) \prod_{k\ge 1} \frac{1}{1-z^k}.$$

The  term   $1/(1-z^k)$  is   the  OGF  of   zero,  one,   two,  three
etc. instances of a cycle of order $k.$

This is the OGF

$$(1-z-z^2+z^3) \prod_{k\ge 1} \frac{1}{1-z^k}.$$

Using the partition function we get for $n\ge 3$

$$p(n) - p(n-1) - p(n-2) + p(n-3).$$

We obtain the sequence

$$1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 13,
\\ 17, 21, 25, 33, 39, 49, \ldots$$

which  points  us  to [OEIS  A00843](https://oeis.org/A008483),  where
these  data are  confirmed  (indeed we  have non-isomorphic  2-regular
graphs).

For  the case  where the  graphs  are labeled  we again  have sets  of
cycles (with dihedral symmetry):

$$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}
\textsc{SET}(\textsc{DHD}_{=3}(\mathcal{Z})
+ \textsc{DHD}_{=4}(\mathcal{Z})
+ \textsc{DHD}_{=5}(\mathcal{Z})
+ \cdots).$$

This gives the EGF

$$\exp
\left(\frac{1}{2} \frac{z^3}{3}
+\frac{1}{2} \frac{z^4}{4}
+\frac{1}{2} \frac{z^5}{5}+\cdots\right)
\\ = \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2} z - \frac{1}{2} \frac{z^2}{2}
+ \frac{1}{2} \log\frac{1}{1-z}\right)
\\ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-z}}
\exp\left(-\frac{z}{2}-\frac{z^2}{4}\right).$$

We get the sequence starting at $n\ge 3$:

$$1, 3, 12, 70, 465, 3507, 30016, 286884, 3026655,
\\ 34944085, 438263364, 5933502822, 86248951243, \ldots$$

which points us to  [OEIS A001205](https://oeis.org/A001205), where we
get confirmation of these data once more.